# Python reclaiming memory after deleting items in a dictionary

Tags: python, memory-management

I have a relatively large dictionary in Python and would like to be able to not only delete items from it, but actually *reclaim* the memory back from these deletions in my program.  I am running across a problem whereby although I delete items from the dictionary and even run the garbage collector manually, Python does not appear to be freeing the memory itself.

A simple example of this:

```
>>> tupdict = {}
# consumes around 2 GB of memory
>>> for i in xrange(12500000):
...   tupdict[i] = (i,i)
... 
# delete over half the entries, no drop in consumed memory
>>> for i in xrange(7500000):
...   del tupdict[i]
... 
>>> import gc
# manually garbage collect, still no drop in consumed memory after this
>>> gc.collect()
0
>>>
```

I imagine what is happening is that although the entries are deleted and garbage collector run, Python does not go ahead and resize the dictionary.  My question is, is there any simple way around this, or am I likely to require a more serious rethink about how I write my program?

Comment: How are you measuring memory consumption?

Comment: Nothing fancy - system monitor in Ubuntu

Comment: Running `gc.collect()` on Python 2.6.5 on Windows XP SP3 seems to free up about 50% of the memory

Comment: @Nick T: Windows releases freed process memory back to the OS for use, Linux does not, so that would be the expected behaviour.  Both of them are doing the "Right Thing" for their purposes.

Comment: related: [Python: garbage collection fails?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9617001/1025391) [How can I explicitly free memory in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1316767/1025391)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A lot of factors go into whether Python returns this memory to the underlying OS or not, which is probably how you're trying to tell if memory is being freed.  CPython has a pooled allocator system that tends to hold on to freed memory so that it can be reused in an efficient manner (but these subsequent allocations won't increase your memory footprint from the perspective of the OS), which might be what you're seeing.

Also, on some unix platforms processes don't release freed memory back to the OS until the application closes (or some other significant event occurs).  Even if you are in a situation where an entire pool has been freed (and thus Python might decide to free() it rather than holding it open for future objects), the OS still won't release this memory to be used by other processes (but can be used for further reallocation within the original process).  In general this is good for reducing memory fragmentation and doesn't have too much of a downside, as the unused process memory will get paged out to disk.  Windows *does* release process memory back to the OS for use by any new allocation (which you can then see in the Task Manager), so trying this on Windows will likely *appear* to give you a different result.

In the end, how to manage deallocated process memory is the purview of the operating system, and there are various schemes (with upsides and downsides) used such that just looking in your system information tool of choice won't necessarily tell you the whole truth.

Answer (score 9):

You're right that Python doesn't resize dictionary back if items are deleted from dictionary. This have nothing to do with OS memory management and garbage collection, it is an implementation detail of Python's dict data structure.

A workaround is to create a new dictionary by copying the old dictionary. Check this great video for more info: http://pyvideo.org/video/276/the-mighty-dictionary-55 (around 26:30 there is an answer).