# Python: garbage collection fails?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

Consider the following script:

```
l = [i for i in range(int(1e8))]
l = []
import gc
gc.collect()
# 0
gc.get_referrers(l)
# [{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, 'l': [], '__package__': None, 'i': 99999999, 'gc': <module 'gc' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}]
del l
gc.collect()
# 0
```

The point is, after all these steps the memory usage of this python process is around 30 % on my machine (Python 2.6.5, any more details on request?).
Here's an excerpt of the output of top:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND  
5478 moooeeeep 20   0 2397m 2.3g 3428 S    0 29.8   0:09.15 ipython
```

resp. `ps aux`:

```
moooeeeep 5478  1.0 29.7 2454720 2413516 pts/2 S+   12:39   0:09 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/ipython gctest.py
```

According to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html?highlight=gc#gc.collect) for `gc.collect`:

> Not all items in some free lists may be freed due to the particular implementation, in particular `int` and `float`.

Does this mean, if I (temporarily) need a large number of different `int` or `float` numbers, I need to export this to C/C++ because the Python GC fails to release the memory?

---

**Update**

Probably the interpreter is to blame, as [this article](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm) suggests:

> It’s that you’ve created 5 million integers simultaneously alive, and each int object consumes 12 bytes. “For speed”, Python maintains an internal free list for integer objects. Unfortunately, that free list is both immortal and unbounded in size. floats also use an immortal & unbounded free list.

The problem however remains, as I cannot avoid this amount of data (timestamp/value pairs from an external source). Am I really forced to drop Python and go back to C/C++ ?

---

**Update 2**

Probably it's indeed the case, that the Python implementation causes the problem. Found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316799/1025391) conclusively explaining the issue and a possible workaround.

Comment: how are you measuring memory usage?

Comment: @strcat the memory usage was reported by [top](http://linux.die.net/man/1/top)

Comment: I tested first with python3.2.2 and the issue is non-existent (memory drops back down to the level of a freshly spawned interpreter), but I do get the same behaviour with 2.7.2 (2.3g RES usage)

Comment: How are you storing the timestamp/value pairs? If it's not on a dictionary (ie. you don't need to efficiently access values by timestamp), then you could try using a NumPy table, pushing the integer/float problem down to C/Fortran, and probably using less memory, anyway.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use a generators based approach? There is a great run-down of using generators here - http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes, thanks for the note on the dictionary. Factoring this out removed a significant amount of occupied memory. (are the hashed keys in that immortal "free lists" as well?)

Comment: @moooeeeep: if they're integer/float values... yes, of course :) It's something that has to do with the object themselves and pre-Python3 pymalloc strategy, not with the use you're making of them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found this also to be answered [by Alex Martelli in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316799/1025391).

> Unfortunately (depending on your version and release of Python) some types of objects use "free lists" which are a neat local optimization but may cause memory fragmentation, specifically by making more an more memory "earmarked" for only objects of a certain type and thereby unavailable to the "general fund".
>
> The only really reliable way to ensure that a large but temporary use of memory DOES return all resources to the system when it's done, is to have that use happen in a subprocess, which does the memory-hungry work then terminates. Under such conditions, the operating system WILL do its job, and gladly recycle all the resources the subprocess may have gobbled up. Fortunately, the multiprocessing module makes this kind of operation (which used to be rather a pain) not too bad in modern versions of Python.
>
> In your use case, it seems that the best way for the subprocesses to accumulate some results and yet ensure those results are available to the main process is to use semi-temporary files (by semi-temporary I mean, NOT the kind of files that automatically go away when closed, just ordinary files that you explicitly delete when you're all done with them).

Fortunately I was able to split the memory intensive work into separate chunks that enabled the interpreter to actually free the temporary memory after each iteration . I used the following wrapper to run the memory intensive function as a subprocess:

```
import multiprocessing

def run_as_process(func, *args):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=args)
    try:
        p.start()
        p.join()
    finally:
        p.terminate()
```

Answer (score 8):

I've done a few tests, and this issue only occurs with CPython 2.x. The issue is gone in CPython 3.2.2 (it drops back to the memory usage of a fresh interpreter) and PyPy 1.8 (python 2.7.2) also drops back down to the same level as a new pypy process.

So no, you don't need to switch to another language. However, there's likely a solution which won't force you to switch to a different Python implementation.

Comment: +1 for your research on different interpreter implementations! Unfortunately I have a bunch of dependencies that are unavailable for Python 3 or PyPy (numpy, matplotlib, pytables etc.).

Answer (score 7):

Your answer may be [here](http://www.evanjones.ca/python-memory.html):

> Python does a lot of allocations and deallocations. All objects,
>   including "simple" types like integers and floats, are stored on the
>   heap. Calling malloc and free for each variable would be very slow.
>   Hence, the Python interpreter uses a variety of optimized memory
>   allocation schemes. The most important one is a malloc implementation
>   called pymalloc, designed specifically to handle large numbers of
>   small allocations. Any object that is smaller than 256 bytes uses this
>   allocator, while anything larger uses the system's malloc. **This
>   implementation never returns memory to the operating system. Instead,
>   it holds on to it in case it is needed again**. This is efficient when
>   it is used again in a short time, but is wasteful if a long time
>   passes before it is needed.

Comment: Note that this is an old text and may not apply any longer, but seems to fit :P

Answer (score 0):

Python tends to do garbage collection fairly intelligently, and in my experience release memory just fine.  It does have a small overhead to take into account (about 15Mb on mine), but beyond that the memory requirements are not that different from C.  If you are dealing with so much data that memory is a serious problem you're probably going to have the same problem in C, so it would be far better to try to change the way you work with your data, for example store it in a pagefile and work with manageable chucks one at a time.

Comment: Not in my experience although I am dealing with data sets and large lists/numpy arrays that have the aforementioned memory issue. I am calling gc.collect and del gc.garbage[:] at least 3-4 times in each tool I wrote.