# MySQLdb - cursor - memory leak?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, memory-leaks

I'm using `MySQLdb` under `Python32` on Windows 7:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 11 2012, 07:12:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>>> import MySQLdb as My
>>> My.version_info
(1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)
```

I'm running service which calls this many times over and over and over again:

```
cursor = self._connection._conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
for i in cursor.fetchall(): pass # Operation that is not important
cursor.close()
gc.collect()
return set() # Will be filled with DB data
```

And memory usage just goes up and up and up, I've already tried [diagnosing it](http://www.huyng.com/posts/python-performance-analysis/) and end up with this:

```
83    23.129 MB     0.000 MB           cursor = self._connection._conn.cursor()
84    23.129 MB     0.000 MB           cursor.execute(sql)
85    23.137 MB     0.008 MB           for i in cursor.fetchall(): pass
86    23.137 MB     0.000 MB           cursor.close()
87
88    23.137 MB     0.000 MB           gc.collect()
89
90    23.137 MB     0.000 MB           return set()
```

Neither `__iter__` API seems to be better:

```
84    23.145 MB     0.000 MB           cursor.execute(sql)
85    23.145 MB     0.000 MB           for i in cursor: pass
86    23.152 MB     0.008 MB           cursor.close()
87
88    23.152 MB     0.000 MB           gc.collect()
89
90    23.152 MB     0.000 MB           return set()
```

And neither looping manually with `fetchone()`:

```
84    23.141 MB     0.000 MB           cursor.execute(sql)
85    23.141 MB     0.000 MB           while True:
86    23.141 MB     0.000 MB               row = cursor.fetchone()
87    23.141 MB     0.000 MB               if not row:
88    23.141 MB     0.000 MB                   break
89    23.148 MB     0.008 MB           cursor.close()
90
91    23.148 MB     0.000 MB           gc.collect()
92
93    23.148 MB     0.000 MB           return set()
```

So why is not memory cleaning back to `23.129MB` (why it always uses new 8KB)? Is the cursor buggy? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The [GC](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/gc.html) module has a debug interface for looking into memory leaks, does that give you any more insight?

Comment: @dwxw It gives me that much info I'm unable to interpret it, if you can provide any good resource for diagnosing this using `gc`, I'll be glad to read it.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC `cursor.fetchall()` builds an in-memory list of rows, and since memory allocation is costly Python tends to retains memory already allocated. Try iterating over your cursor instead, ie `for row in cursor: do_something_with(row)`.

Comment: I was already writing down edit with different methods. Always the same result... `+8KB`

Comment: Plus `gc.collect()` should take care of that, shouldn't it?

Comment: I notice that in the two methods not using `cursor.fetchall()` the memory usage increases on the call to `cursor.close()`... You should perhaps 1/ set the pass statement on it's own line and 2/ add some noop statement just before the call to `cursor.close()`. You may also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617001/python-garbage-collection-fails and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python/ for more on the topic. Finally note that virtual memory management is a complex topic... But I assume you already know this

Comment: Ho and yes: if the memory is used by the `cursor` object itself, `gc.collect()` _won't_ collect it as you still have a reference to it in the current namespace. Adding a `del cursor` between `cursor.close()` and `gc.collect()` might be a good idea here ;)