# when memory is allocated to variable in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, memory-management

As in java

```
int requires 4 bytes
float requires 4 bytes
char requires 2 bytes
```

but in python we donot declare type of variable so,

> Q. When memory is allocated to the variable?

As in the below example different type of data is allocated to same variable

```
var = 10
print var
print type(var) #<type 'int'>

var = 10.5
print var
print type(var) #<type 'float'>

var = "python"
print var
print type(var) #<type 'str'>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In-memory size of a Python structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331471/in-memory-size-of-a-python-structure)

Comment: @OmairMajid this link doesnot only contains answer of part a

Comment: Related: [How is memory allocated for variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42543225/1364007).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory for the **variable** is allocated when the variable is created - e.g. when you enter the function, in case of local variables.

The memory for the **object** is allocated when the object is created, regardless of whether it is assigned to a variable.

In Java terms, you can think of all Python variables as holding references to `Object`s. This means that each variable only requires a fixed pointer-sized amount of memory to "hold" (refer to) its contents. That's why Python variables can easily refer to data of different type throughout their lifetime.